# How to update a dataset by an doctrine object?

Tags: orm, doctrine

I've been working with Doctrine a while now, but I'm not very happy with it.

I try to do following:
(the Primary Key of the User Table is an autoincement with name userID)

```
$user = new Mode_User();
$user->set('username', 'BenKenobi');
$user->save();
```

it works OK and Doctrine saves it to the database. Now I want it to update this object by do this:

```
$user->set('email', 'BenKenobi@etc.de');
$user->save();
```

This will throw no error but nothing happens. Does someone has a tipp for me beacuse that is the way a ORM should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I assume you are using Doctrine 1.x)*

I suggest that you [read the fine docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction) for Doctrine and work through its [examples](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction-to-models/en#introduction-to-models).

What you want is similar to this:

```
$user = new Mode_User();
$user->username = 'BenKenobi;
$user->email = 'BenKenobi@etc.de';
$user->save();
```

You don't use `set` explicitly but you set the value for a property of the model. Of course all this functionallity depends on a proper set up in the database and that you set all of the models properties accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we are using Doctrine 1.2.
And i found the problem. Ther is an preUpdate()-Method in the User-Model. When i comment the method out then everything functions but with this method not. I decided to make a query an execute it.